# How to list most frequent text values within a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm an intermediate excel user trying to solve an issue that feels a little over my head. Basically, I'm working with a spreadsheet which contains a number of orders associated with customer account #s and which have up to 5 metadata "tags" associated with them. I want to be use that customer account # to pull the 5 most commonly occurring metadata tags in order.

[Here is a mock up of the first set of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JmgL.png)

```
Account Number  Order Number    Metadata            
5043                  1         A   B   C   D
4350                  2         B   D       
4350                  3         B   C       
5043                  4         A   D       
5043                  5         C   D       
1204                  6         A   B       
5043                  7         A   D       
1204                  8         D   B       
4350                  9         B   D       
5043                 10         A   C   D
```

[and the end result I'm trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJBKy.png)

```
Account Number  Most Common Tag 2nd 3rd 4th 5th
5043                  A         C   B   N/A
4350                  B         D   C   N/A N/A
1204                  B         A   C   N/A N/A
```

I was trying to work with the formula suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070201/how-to-output-the-most-common-value-and-the-number-of-occurrences-of-that-value):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7)),COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7),0)))
```

But I don't know how to a) use the customer account # as a precondition for counting the text values within the range. b) how to circumvent the fact that the Match forumula only wants to work with a single column of data and c) how to read the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th most common values from this range.

The way I'm formatting this data isn't set in stone. I suspect the way I'm organizing this information is holding me back from simpler solutions, so any suggestions on re-thinking my organization would be just as helpful as insights on how to create a formula to do this.

Comment: `ARRAYFORMULA()` is not Excel it is Google sheets.

Comment: Also post the data as text in the original post so we do not need to retype the sheets to test the formulas.  If you can't format it correctly just post it and someone will help with the formatting.

Comment: Thanks, updated with text. Yes, I'm working in Google sheets. Wasn't sure if I should mention that or not.

Comment: The problem is your data is setup poorly.  The metadata should be in a single column, not multiple columns, especially because each Account Number already has multiple rows.  With a data setup like you currently have, getting results that you want will be much more complex

Comment: Yeah, I figured. so long as the end result can still list the individual tags in order of frequency, than having them on a single column sounds good if it makes things simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this kind of frequency analysis using built-in functions is likely to be a frustrating exercise. Since you are working with Google Sheets, take advantage of the [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), written in JavaScript and placed into a script bound to the sheet (Tools > Script Editor).

The function I wrote for this purpose is below. Entering something like `=tagfrequency(A2:G100)` in the sheet will produce desired output:

```
+----------------+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Account Number | Most Common Tag | 2nd | 3rd | 4th | 5th |
| 5043           | D               | A   | C   | B   | N/A |
| 4350           | B               | D   | C   | N/A | N/A |
| 1204           | B               | A   | D   | N/A | N/A |
+----------------+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

#### Custom function

```
function tagFrequency(arr) {
  var dict = {};                   // the object in which to store tag counts
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var acct = arr[i][0];
    if (acct == '') {
      continue;                    // ignore empty rows
    }
    if (!dict[acct]) {
      dict[acct] = {};             // new account number
    }
    for (var j = 2; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      var tag = arr[i][j];
      if (tag) {
        if (!dict[acct][tag]) {
          dict[acct][tag] = 0;      // new tag 
        }
        dict[acct][tag]++;          // increment tag count
      }
    }
  }
                    //  end of recording, begin sorting and output 
  var output = [['Account Number', 'Most Common Tag', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th']];
  for (acct in dict) {
    var tags = dict[acct];
    var row = [acct].concat(Object.keys(tags).sort(function (a,b) {
      return (tags[a] < tags[b] ? 1 : (tags[a] > tags[b] ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : -1)));
    }));                        // sorting by tag count, then tag name
    while (row.length < 6) {
      row.push('N/A');          // add N/A if needed 
    }
    output.push(row);           // add row to output 
  }
  return output;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Playing around with this and i think it will work perfectly. Now, in practice, the way this data is laid out there is several columns of extra information associated with each order in between the accounts and the tags. Is there a way to modify this function to skip over that information? In this case, there are thirteen additional columns of information in between the account # and tags that I don't want to be read as "tags" by the formula.

Comment: You should modify the loop over `j` accordingly. Right now it's `for (var j = 2; j < arr[i].length; j++)`, meaning it begins with 2. So, j=0 is account number, j=1 is order number (skipped), and tags begin with j=2. If you have 13 more columns to skip, j will begin with 15 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

You also could get this report:

```
Account Number     Tag    count 
          1204      B         2
          1204      A         1
          1204      D         1
          4350      B         3
          4350      D         2
          4350      C         1
          5043      D         5
          5043      A         4
          5043      C         3
          5043      B         1
```

with the formula:

```
    =QUERY(
     {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",ArrayFormula(REPT(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&",",5))),",")),
      TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:G,A2:A<>"")&" ,")),",")),
      TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(rept("1,",counta(A2:A)*5),","))
     },
   "select Col1, Col2, Count(Col3) where Col2 <>' ' group by Col1, Col2
    order by Col1, Count(Col3) desc label Col1 'Account Number', Col2 'Tag'")
```

The formula will count the number of occurrences of any tag.

Comment: Thanks, Max! I really appreciate this. Because the goal of this formula is to basically create a summary of an account's preferences, this report isn't ideal, though.