# How do I return the most frequently occurring text value in range of text values in a Google Docs spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range `B2:B7` which contains text values that stand for something, but what I want is to have a cell display the text value that comes up the most in that range.

So for example if my range contained the text values {"red", "green", "green", "blue", "green", "blue"}, the average value displayed in the cell would be "green".

How do I do this?

Comment: You can't have an average of a group of words.  Do you mean the value that appears most frequently?

Comment: @Dan Yes, the most frequent value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for my actual problem that was simplified in my question. (It's a record of every hour of my year so far.)

[image: My spreadsheet displaying every hour of my day with the average day at the first row]

The first row is the average day.

I used [chiliNUT's method in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070334/8028410), in which he provided this nice and simple line that solved my specific case (assuming the values are in the range A1:A7):

```
=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7)),COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7),0))
```

Yes I had to copy and edit it 24 times but it's worth it. Thanks to those who answered too.

Answer (score 1):

[`=SORTN(A1:A7,1,2,COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7),0)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a numeric column which will allow you to count each row easily.

[image]

Then check for unique values in column A

`=UNIQUE(A2:A7)`

The result in this example would be

[image]

Then count the frequency of each unique value using a `sumif` function `=sumif(A:A,E1,B:B)`

Last lookup the word that corresponds with the max value `=vlookup(max(D:D),D:E,2,false)` (cell G2 below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution which I found here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/4cpTjqVH0bs

Assuming your values are in column A you can get a result showing the unique values and their corresponding counts using the following:

```
=QUERY({A:A,A:A},"Select Col1, Count(Col2) Where Col1<>'' Group by Col1 Label Col1 'Name',Count(Col2) 'Count'")
```

More information on the QUERY function here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Dan, I found my solution using ```=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7)),COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7),0))```